# Register a default instance in StructureMap

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

I have a class (`MyService`) that has a static property (`MyService.Context`) which represents a current context (which is specific to currently logged in user, so it changes).

What i'm trying to achieve i

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.For<IMyService>().Use<MyInstance>(c => c.Use(MyService.Context));
            });
```

I.e. so that for every `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyService>()` i get a reference to `MyService.Context`

Is that doable?

**UPDATE**

I can't use a singleton pattern since `MyService.Context` changes depending on the user making a request (via HttpContext).

In the pseudo-code above lambda parameter `c` represents a SM context, so that i can return a custom result for each request. I'm aware of SM's `Intercept()` but it's fired *after* the object is constructed - not *instead*.

Comment: Are multiple users using the application at the same time (like in a web app)? If so, you cannot use a static property to hold user specific information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can work with a property there is the possibility to add a `OnCreation` method. The Action provided is executed against the instance just after creation:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IMyService>()
             .Use<MyInstance>()
             .OnCreation(x => x.Context = MyService.Context;
        });
```

Or you can use lazy initialization and provide a `Func` to the `Use` method which is executed whenever a new instance is needed. This should execute in the right context:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IMyService>()
             .Use<MyInstance>(() => new MyInstance(MyService.Context);
        });
```

I hope one of this methods works for you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've realized that i didn't make it clear enough and the code was not demonstrating what i wanted to do. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, i used x.For<IMyService>().Use<MyInstance>(() => MyService.Context), which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the MyService has a ctor argument for the IContext:

```
For<IContext>().Add(c => MyService.Context).Named("context");
For<IMyService>().Use<MyService>()
    .Ctor<IContext>().Is(c => c.GetInstance<IContext>("context"));
```

or if you want to default the context for all dependees:

```
For<IContext>().Use(() => MyService.Context);
For<IMyService>().Use<MyService>();
```

The lambda expression will in both cases cause the context to be resolved upon requesting the MyService instance.