# asp.net identity 2.1 injecting IAuthenticationManager using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap, asp.net-identity-2

Can anyone point me in the direction of some samples or instructions on how to achieve this please?

Comment: Full code is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27244289/351204

Answer (score 9):

I have not used StructureMap, but I have done this with Autofac and SimpleInjector.

Autofac registration would look like this:

```
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>();
```

Registration in SimpleInjector looks like this:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
```

And from looking on StructureMap tutorial I can guess that registration there would be something like this:

```
ForRequestedType<IAuthenticationManager>()
    .TheDefaultIs(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication)
```

Comment: This is what I had thought it would be but it throws an error as the HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication is null.

Comment: This means you are trying to resolve `IAuthenticationManager` before there `OwinContext` is created for the request. Usually this happens when you try to resolve it without http-request, i.e. in `Global.asax`

Comment: That is the problem, where should I be doing this?

Comment: Why do you need `IAuthenticationManager` before the request happens?

Comment: I don't. Where should I be initializing my container so that the OwinContext is present?

Comment: mm.. only reason I can think of is that container resolving objects in Global.asax, and one of the resolved objects needs `IAuthenticationManager`. This caught me once as well, I needed `UserManager` in `Global.asax` to make sure Admin user is created. And `UserManager` was dependent on `IAuthManager`. Are you not doing something like this?

Comment: Also there is a chance that StructureMap creates all the instances on registration and tries to resolve `IAuthManager` at the same time. Try doing late resolving. Something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6567855/809357

Comment: Thanks, that post helped a lot.

Comment: Good! Can you post your solution as an answer please. I did struggle with this very issue, would be good if the solution is available to the community.

Comment: It was as simple as:
For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use<MyAuthenticationManager>(() => new MyAuthenticationManager(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

Answer (score 8):

This initially came about by converting Identity to use int as the unique key values as described [here](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx).

I then extended this and created a custom AuthenticationManager using IAuthenticationManager.

I then setup StructureMap as follows:

```
For<IAuthenticationManager>()
    .Use<MyAuthenticationManager>(
     () => new MyAuthenticationManager(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

Thanks @trailmax

Comment: Nice solution. Decorator for the win!